# missing 1 required positional argument (IP checker)

Tags: python

This is an IP address problem where I need to implement a function is_valid_IP that takes an arbitrary string and determines if it represents a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.

```
IPv4_STRING = "127.0.0.1"
IPv4_INVALID_STRING = "300.0.0.1"
IPv6_STRING = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334"
IPv6_INVALID_STRING = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334:7334"
INVALID_IP_STRING = "Some arbitrary string"

def is_valid_IPv4_octet(octet: str):
    for element in ip_list:
        if int(element) < 0 or int(element) > 255 :
            return False
    return True

def is_valid_IPv4(ip: str):
    if ip.count('.') != 3:
        return False
        quit()
    ip_list = list(map(str, ip.split('.')))
    return is_valid_IPv4_octet(ip_list)


def is_valid_IPv6_hextet(hextet: str):
    for element in ip_list:
        if int(element,16) < 0 or int(element,16)>65535 :
            return False
    return True

def is_valid_IPv6(ip: str):
    if ip.count(':')!=7:
        return False
        quit()
    ip_list=list(map(str,ip.split(':')))
    return is_valid_IPv6_hextet(ip_list)

def is_valid_IP(ip: str):
   if( is_valid_IPv4() or is_valid_IPv6() == True):
       print("Valid IP Address")
   else:
       print("Invalid IP Address")



print(
    f"{IPv4_STRING} is a valid IP Address:",
    is_valid_IP(IPv4_STRING))
print(
    f"{IPv4_INVALID_STRING} is a valid IP Address:",
    is_valid_IP(IPv4_INVALID_STRING),
)
print(
    f"{IPv6_STRING} is a valid IP Address:",
    is_valid_IP(IPv6_STRING))
print(
    f"{IPv6_INVALID_STRING} is a valid IP Address:",
    is_valid_IP(IPv6_INVALID_STRING),
)
print(
    f"{INVALID_IP_STRING} is a valid IP Address:",
    is_valid_IP(INVALID_IP_STRING),
)
```

The IDE gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jerry\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    is_valid_IP(ip)
  File "C:\Users\jerry\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 38, in is_valid_IP
    if( is_valid_IPv4() or is_valid_IPv6() == True):
TypeError: is_valid_IPv4() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ip'
```

Can someone tell me why? I've been surfing a bit, the general opinion is i need to put something in the bracket of the function. But in this case there is somehting inside...So i dont really know where went wrong.

Comment: Look at the function `def is_valid_IPv4(ip: str):` and then look at `is_valid_IPv4()`. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the arguments here:

```
def is_valid_IP(ip: str):
#added ip
  if( is_valid_IPv4(ip) or is_valid_IPv6(ip) == True):
      print("Valid IP Address")
  else:
      print("Invalid IP Address")
```

Also since the functions already return True or False you can get rid of the `== True`

```
def is_valid_IP(ip: str):
  if( is_valid_IPv4(ip) or is_valid_IPv6(ip)):
      print("Valid IP Address")
  else:
      print("Invalid IP Address")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def is_valid_IP(ip: str):
   if( is_valid_IPv4() or is_valid_IPv6() == True):
       print("Valid IP Address")
   else:
       print("Invalid IP Address")
```

here you are calling 2 functions `is_valid_IPv4` and `is_valid_IPv6`. These 2 need an input which is ip.